# Show that the volume of a sphere of radius $r$ is $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$

Tags: calculus, integration

If we place the sphere so that its center is at the origin, then the plane $P_x$ intersects the sphere in a circle whose radius is $y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.So the cross-sectional area is $$A(x) = \pi y^2 = \pi (r^2 - x^2)$$

[image]

Where I get lost is in the integration. How does $2\pi\int_{0}^{r} (r^2-x^2)dx$ integrate to $2\pi \bigg[ r^2x - \frac{x^3}{3}\bigg]_{0}^{r}$ ? In my mind it integrates to $2\pi \bigg[ \frac{1}{3} r^3 - \frac{1}{3}x^3\bigg]_{0}^{r}$

What am I overlooking here? I am really confused why $r^2 \to r^2x$ if it's just a simple power series integration.

Comment: $\int_0^r r^2 \, dx = r^2 \int_0^r dx$, because $x$ is the variable of integration and $r$ is constant.

Comment: Oh, my god. You are right, $r$ is the constant radius. Thank you

Comment: @T.Bongers Consider converting your comment to an answer so that this question is removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138).

Comment: @Brian Feel free to yourself; I don't really care to turn my $\epsilon$ into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, $r$ is a constant, so 
$$\int_0^r(r^2-x^2)dx=r^2\int_0^rdx-\int_0^rx^2dx=r^3-\frac{r^3}3=\frac23r^3$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume area of spherical shell is $A = 4\pi r^2$. Expand the shell by thickness $dr$. Then $dA = 4\pi r^2 dr$. Integrate from 0 to R. Get $\frac{4}{3}R^3$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for MathJax symbols.